# index.php? in the beginning of WordPress permalink redirects to homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I am migrating a website from a custom PHP system to WordPress. The old url structure is example.com/index.php?postname. I added a code to functions.php in order to set up the permalink structure in that way and it was updated but every time when i try to visit a post i am redirected to the homepage. Why is this happening?

Thank you a lot in advance!

Comment: `example.com/index.php?postname` means browser will hit `example.com/index.php` and as get param `postname`.  So you are visiting `example.com/index.php`

Comment: Thank you, and how can I change that, is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found out that ? in the url is causing the issue. I am still seaching a way to add it without breaking the site.